# Data retrieval from WAL since cluster init

Tags: restore, disaster-recovery, postgresql-14

[Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html) is very clear that to utilize the WAL archive for replication or restore, a base backup must first be in place, upon which later WAL records can be applied.

Firstly, would it be conceptually possible to replay the entire WAL history from record ...01 to recreate the system without a base backup?  If not, why not?  And if so, why is this not a supported restore scenario?

Secondly, is it possible - using just the static WAL archive - to insinuate what data changes were occurring (which could further be interpreted as INSERTs, UPDATEs, etc)?  The point being that even if a restore to the exact state couldn't be obtained down to the internal oids, a logical recreation of the state might be obtainable.  The available tooling that provide logical interpretations of the WAL (wal2json, et al) seem to run via an active replication slot, which provides an advantage in knowing the logical state of the database in realtime.  The question here is if a similar logical interpretation can be achieved using just a static archive (with a complete history or otherwise).

Comment: I suppose the dev team would be able to answer this. @ErwinBrandstetter, perhaps?